# How to export subform without navigation pane and vba

Tags: ms-access-2010, export-to-excel

I have in MS Access main navigation form with several Tabs. These Tabs display subforms (in Datasheet view). I need to export these data to Excel, but the export button (on the ribbon "External Data") exports the empty main form only.
The users cannot use the Navigation pane because it is hidden. Is it any possibility to export subform by native Access function?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create buttons on the tabs, and code those buttons to export the SubForm Data, using the DoCmd.OutputTo method. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx)

Comment: I tried first to find solution without buttons and vba. But if there is not other way...

Comment: using buttons and VBA is a much better option than using the normal commands.